# convert for DateTime in Flutter does not seem to work correctly

Tags: datetime, flutter, milliseconds

converting with milliseconds differs from the original after conversion.
Microsecond conversion works fine.

Testcode:

```
print("---Milliseconds:");
DateTime dateTimeStart = DateTime.now();
print("Datetime: $dateTimeStart");
int milliseconds = dateTimeStart.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
print("Milliseconds: $milliseconds");
DateTime dateTimeEnd = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(milliseconds);
print("DateTimeEnd: $dateTimeEnd");
print("---Microseconds:");
print("Datetime: $dateTimeStart");
int microseconds = dateTimeStart.microsecondsSinceEpoch;
print("Microseconds: $microseconds");
DateTime dateTimeEnd2 = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(microseconds);
print("DateTimeEnd2: $dateTimeEnd2");
```

Output:

I/flutter (26574): ---Milliseconds:
I/flutter (26574): Datetime: 2020-05-13 18:40:12.675351 <----- not equal among each other !!!
I/flutter (26574): Milliseconds: 1589388012675
I/flutter (26574): DateTimeEnd: 2020-05-13 18:40:12.675 <----- not equal among each other !!!
I/flutter (26574): ---Microseconds:
I/flutter (26574): Datetime: 2020-05-13 18:40:12.675351 <----- equal
I/flutter (26574): Microseconds: 1589388012675351
I/flutter (26574): DateTimeEnd2: 2020-05-13 18:40:12.675351 <----- equal

Or do I have a bug somewhere?

---

flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836], locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 1.17.0 at C:\AndroidStudio\FlutterSDK\flutter
    • Framework revision e6b34c2b5c (11 days ago), 2020-05-02 11:39:18 -0700
    • Engine revision 540786dd51
    • Dart version 2.8.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3) 
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\richa\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.45.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\richa\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.10.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM J510UN • a29a4ea7 • android-arm • Android 6.0.1 (API 23)

• No issues found!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. When you do millisecond conversion you are losing the greater precision that using microseconds provides. You're dropping all of the additional microseconds that the `DateTime` contains when you use milliseconds.

Comment: @user13535406 Does this make sense?